# Why is JavaScript regex catching whitespace when I do not tell it to do so?

Tags: javascript, regex, whitespace

With the following code:

```js
var firefox = "Mozilla/5.0 (Android; Mobile; rv:32.0) Gecko/32.0 Firefox/32.0";
var chrome = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 4 Build/KTU84Q) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.57 Mobile Safari/537.36";

var newf = firefox.replace(/.*?(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*?)/, "$1 $2");
var newc = chrome.replace(/.*?(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*?)/, "$1 $2");
console.log(newf);
console.log(newc);
```

I get this in console:

```
Firefox 32.0
Chrome 38.0.2125.57 Mobile Safari/537.36
```

and I only want to get `browser_name version`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it seems to be working fine.see   http://regex101.com/r/pD5sV6/5

Comment: The reason the `Chrome` doesn't work is there is text after it you don't match/replace in the regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use this regex:

```
var newc = chrome.replace(/.*?(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*).*/, "$1 $2");
//=> "Chrome 38.0.2125.57"
```

1. Don't make `[\d\.]*` lazy using `[\d\.]*?`
2. Add `.*` after `[\d\.]*` to remove all the text after version #

Answer (score 4):

Your regex is not taking into account the last `Mobile Safari/537.36`; as [vks pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25922292/why-javacript-regex-is-catching-whitespace-when-i-do-not-say-it-to-do-so#comment40578775_25922292) the regex ignores that last bit since your pattern succeeds completely after `Chrome/38.0.2125.57` matches.

Had you added the end-terminator character (`$`) to your pattern, it would have failed and it would have be apparent as to the problem. [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in Javascript finds the part of the text that matches the regex and replaces it, not the whole input string.

---

You could add `.*` at the end to sort of *'burn'* through those last characters, causing the regex to match the *whole line* and thus causing a replace to remove those bits. This also requires you make the previous match group non-lazy by removing the `?` after `[\d\.]*`.

I'd also add `^` and `$` at the beginning/end of your pattern to signify the beginning and end of the input string (it's good form to do so), as well as optionally add `/gm`, which tells the regex to match each line (could potentially be useful in your case), though neither of these additions are required.

```
/^.*?(Firefox|Chrome)\/([\d\.]*).*$/gm
```

Comment: And after all these edits this regex has become similar to my answer :)

Comment: @anubhava Funny, I don't see an explanation as to why `replace()` is doing what it does in your answer, nor did you explain why your code works or why it's the solution to their problem. I was writing this answer when you submitted yours.